# User profile page layout borked: #large-user-info needs clearfix

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

> [image: Profile page]

Eww, layout looks borkey. It doesn't seem to happen everywhere, but it appears 
`#large-user-info` is missing a clearfix. Add something like this:

```
#large-user-info::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the suggested fix. I have pushed it to dev. The change will be on live after our next production build.